# Android ActionBar design in API greater than 14

Tags: android, android-layout

Can I design my Android ActionBar like this?

If yes, give me a starter. I am not new to android design. 
Application name with logo is already centered but the little red strip on bottom is difficult as fas as I can understand. If somebody can help.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

create custom layout and design whatever you want then add that layout into the actionbar object.

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();  //to support lower version too
actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
View customView=getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.yourlayout, null);
actionBar.setCustomView(customView);
```

Comment: What about the Layout then? I mean Java code is ok for me but what about the Layout design in XML like same like that image.

Comment: use .9png image to dispaly the filter background image

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom layout according to your requirement in an xml file say,

activity_custom_actionbar.xml

Then include this in your java file using,

```
 ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();    
 actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.activity_custom_actionbar);
 getActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
```